# SQL procedure vs. script - terminology

Tags: sql

When one wants to update records in database using Data Manipulation Language, what would be right terminology to use:

1. UPDATE RECORDS IN TABLE VIA STORED PROCEDURE or
2. UPDATE RECORDS IN TABLE VIA SCRIPT (or UPDATE SCRIPT)
3. something else...

NOTE: I know that procedure is not same as script, I wrote question in rush. Real question is if you want to write to your DBA that the defect could be fixed by using (1) or (2) or (3) what would be the right choice. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: Update table using stored procedure and update table using a script

Answer (score 3):

If you want to DBA fix some defect, best approach is to write a script file with UPDATE statements, and save it for later use.

If you want that someone else (Job, DBA, App Code) frequently execute same code for updating records in table, then write stored procedure.

Good thing is that you can pass a parameter to stored procedure to affect on range of rows which will be updated.

ONE IMPORTANT THING: Stored procedure are optimized from SQL Optimizer and SQL creates most effective execution plan for it. When you execute it again, SQL find cached execution plan for that procedure and apply it. In this way, you achieve better performance when using stored procedure over script.

Answer (score 2):

A "script" sounds to me like one or more statements that are sent to the database, to perform some action.

A "stored procedure" is that same bunch of statements, but already stored in the database so it can be activated with a simple command.

Answer (score 1):

"Update via stored procedure" is not a synonim to "update via script", so why do you choosing either one or another as term?

Stored procedure - is an object (yes, technically it is some kind of scripit) created and stored in database.

Script - is just a script (sequence of statements). It can be stored in file or just created and executed "on the fly".

Answer (score 1):

If you use just one `update` statement, then the most appropriate expression is "update records in table via update **statement**". If you use set of `update` statements, then it will be a **script**.

Procedure is an another DBMS object, usually called stored procedure. You can also define a procedure that update data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Non of the options fit me very well. Sure, if you know an update is being made from a *Stored Procedure* specifically, that would be fine to use. But an update can be done from many other ways and a *Stored procedure* can do many other things than just update.

I usually talk about `queries` and `statements`, for example:

> Update records in a table via an update statement within a Stored Procedure

As for the use of script, I'm personally not that fond of it. There are already many more specific ways to talk about scripts, like Stored procedures, user defined functions, etc. That, for me, is a collection of statements and/or queries.